# Npm ERR code EJSONPARSE - Failed to parse json

Tags: json, node.js

So I was just about to setup this login form for my page using node.js
I ran

> npm init

and went trough the various steps to complete it. When I was all done with that, and the package.json file had been created I added these lines of code"

```
 dependencies": {
         "bcryptjs": "*",
         "body-parser": "*",
         "connect-flash": "*",
         "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
         "express": "*",
         "express-handlebars": "*",
         "express-messages": "*",
         "express-session": "*",
         "express-validator": "*",
         "mongodb": "*",
         "mongoose": "*",
         "passport": "*",
         "passport-http": "*",
         "passport-local": "*"   }
```

I now ran the command

> npm install

But ended up getting these ERRORS

```
npm ERR! file /Users/albingroen/Desktop/newProject/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\n' at 26:5
npm ERR!   }
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! File: /Users/albingroen/Desktop/newProject/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/albingroen/.npm/_logs/2017-04-04T18_52_34_920Z-debug.log
```

I have tried following things:

- Cleaning the node cache
- Using different terminal
- Updating node.js
- Updating mongodb
- Changing location of package.json
- Running npm install without the added dependencies
- Deleting the nodemodules mapp

**I really don't know what to do anymore. Somebody got an idea?**

Comment: Not sure why you did all that when the error is pretty clear: the JSON in `package.json` contains a syntax error on line 26. Try running it through a validator [like this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: take a look at your first line. dependencies ends with `"`
Change it to `dependencies: {`

Comment: @TobiasLins that should be `"dependencies"`, as it should be valid JSON.

Comment: @TobiasLins keys without quotes are valid in JS, not in JSON.

Comment: You can check valid JSON tools. Ref: https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print

Answer (score 24):

I had the same error. It is caused by wrong syntax within your package.json.
I solved it by removing an unnecessary ',' at the end of my last dependency, but it can be different for everyone. Looking over the package.json syntax would be the best bet.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the unnecessary commas, that is, at the end of each object in your package.json.

My path: SolutionName/ClientApp/src/package.json
In my case it was in "lodash".

```
"resolutions": {
 "url-parse": "> = 1.5.0",
 "lodash": "> = 4.17.21", <-- I deleted this comma!
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check Whether You have created the package.json file. If not create it and initialize it with {}.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `package.json` and add

```
"web-vitals": "^3.1.0"
```

to your dependencies.

That has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above answer, i checked my files for any unnecessary ',' but everything looked good.

I tried this in terminal, and it worked.

```
npm run start
```

and then, install your dependencies, for me i did it as

```
npm install express mongoose
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing some "}" or something in your package.json file just check it out or compare it with the old version of your file it helped me out many times

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error because I forget to give a comma "," in my JSON file. After putting comma in JSON file it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my react project ,in package.json name of my project was given in a letter.When i changed it to a word in small case command worked for e then.

Answer (score -1):

i faced the same error. I solved removing the extra commas